# Windows 7 - WriteProcessMemory works but no effect can be seen

Tags: c++, c, windows

I know there are numerous questions about this, but none seem to solve my problem.

I was playing around with the WriteProcessMemory function. It all seems pretty straightforward, but I'm stuck with one problem here and can't seem to find a solution.

**What I have:**

1) The "victim" - process which memory should be altered

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    SetConsoleTitle("MyTest");

    int var = 5;

    printf ("%p\n\n\n\n", &var);

    while (1)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", var);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2) The "attacker" - the process that attempts to alter the "var" variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {

    HWND hwnd;       
    HANDLE handle;   
    DWORD pid;       

    hwnd = FindWindow(0, "MyTest");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    int NewVar = 89; 

    SIZE_T bytesWritten = 0;

    printf ("%d\n", WriteProcessMemory(handle, (void *)ADDRESS, &NewVar, 4, &bytesWritten)); 

    printf("%d\n", bytesWritten);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, ADDRESS is what the "victim" tells us about the location of its "var" variable.

**The problem:**

When I launch the victim and then start the attacker, WriteProcessMemory returns 1 and bytesWritten is set to 4 - so, in theory, all went good. The problem is the client still printfs 5, 5, 5 instead of 89. I've tried it with another examples as well, to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Not sure if it's necessary, but the OS is a 32-bit Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Take a look at the `pid`. You'll find that you're writing to the wrong process.

Comment: That FindWindow will find cmd.exe's PID, because most likely you are setting cmd.exe's window title with SetConsoleTitle, as Raymond said, just change your way of finding PID of victim process, try to do that with process name of victim process.

Comment: No, the console window is owned by csrss.exe on old Windows versions, conhost.exe on current ones.  You are corrupting the process, I recommend a reboot asap.  Find the process by name or start it yourself.  The variable must be declared *volatile*.

Comment: Alright, turns out I was indeed finding the wrong process ID. If I hardcode it it works nice. Thanks everyone :).

Comment: I have this same problem, but have not been able to solve it. I know that I am changing the right memory because I also do a ReadProcessMemory before and after the write and see that it changes from the original value to my target value, but in the victim process it is not changed. I have added volatile to the variable, tried taking the reference and then de-referencing, and using malloc to make the memory (this resulted in the wrong memory being changed though, don't know why).

Answer (score 1):

Try `volatile int var = 5;`. It's possible that the compiler never reloads the variable from RAM, but keeps it in a register.